# Storing return type and arguments type of a method

Tags: c++, c++11, compile-time, decltype

Is it possible to determine and store the return type of `SomeMethod` using `decltype` (if it is the best way to do it, otherwise what is the best way to do it) at compile time ?

Is it also possible to use the same tool to store a type list of the arguments of `SomeMethod` ?

This idea behind that is to make them easily accessible from outside the class using getters.

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
    typedef [???] ProcRetType;
    typedef [???] ProcArgTypeList;

public:
    SomeClass() { }
    ~SomeClass() noexcept { }

    SomeType SomeMethod( SomeType1 arg1, SomeType2 arg2 ) { }

    // Data members
private:
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the return type, you can just use `decltype`:

```
typedef decltype(SomeMethod(std::declval<SomeType1>(), std::declval<SomeType2>())) ProcRetType;
```

For the parameters, you'll need a helper trait. That can also be used for the return type, like this:

```
template <class Func>
struct Helper;

template <class T, class R, class... Arg>
struct Helper<R (T::*)(Arg...)>
{
  typedef std::tuple<Arg...> ArgTypes;
  typedef R ReturnType;
};
```

And then use it like this:

```
typedef Helper<decltype(&SomeClass::SomeMethod)>::ReturnType ProcRetType;
typedef Helper<decltype(&SomeClass::SomeMethod)>::ArgTypes ProcArgTypeList;
```

I'm using `std::tuple` to represent the type list - other representations are also possible, such as [Boost.MPL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/mpl/doc/index.html).

You might need to provide a few other partial specialisations of `Helper` to account for `const` functions (and possibly `volatile` and old-style variadic functions as well, if that applies to you).

Comment: Thanks for the explicit answer, and nice technique. But I get the following errors: `Error - no member named 'SomeMethod' in 'SomeClass'
Error - non-friend class member 'ReturnType' cannot have a qualified name
Error - typedef declarator cannot be qualified
Error - expected ';' at end of declaration list` which I don't understand in that context.

Comment: `Helper<&SomeClass::SomeMethod>::ReturnType` looks wrong. Should probably be `Helper<decltype(&SomeClass::SomeMethod)>::ReturnType`.

Comment: Nice correction. BUT, why do I absolutely have to declare my `typedef`s after the declaration of `SomeMethod` in `SomeClass` ?

Comment: @Athanase because the compiler hasn't seen the type yet.

Comment: Dummy question, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can represent types with [`std::type_info`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info) objects (constructed via the [`typeid` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid)) and store them with [`std::type_index`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index).

As an example you can do:

```
auto ret_type = std::type_index(typeid(ProcRetType));
```

to store `ProcRetType` in a variable.

And due to the fact that `std::type_index` is both [CopyConstructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyConstructible) and [CopyAssignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyAssignable), you can also store them in containers like `std::vector`. For example:

```
std::vector<std::type_index> vec;
vec.emplace_back(typeid(int));
vec.emplace_back(typeid(double));
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did not mention that I want do to this a compile time. With something like `typedef decltype(SomeClass::SomeMethod) ProcRetType;`